# How to call 2 web API in Observable function angular 8 service?

Tags: observable, angular8, subscribe

I'm having service ts for all webapi call (with return observable) which I call(subscribe) from Component ts file in my angular 8. I have requirement like in service function, I need to call 2 http webapi calls (2nd is dependent on 1st response) and I want to return observable of 2nd web api call. But that is not working. 
below is my service function :

getDetailNames(type: string): Observable {

```
  const url = this.API_URL + 'detail';

   this._httpClient.get(url).pipe(map(resp => {
     console.log("test");
     console.log(resp);
     localStorage.setItem("nameType", resp.name);

     const url1 = this.API_URL + 'detailname';
     return this._httpClient.get(url1).pipe(map((res) => {
       return this._httpBaseService.handleAPIResponse(res);
     }), catchError((error: any) => this._httpBaseService.handleAPIError(error)));
  }))
}
```

}